# Labels for Pie Chart

Tags: r

Need some help to get me over the finish line. Importing a XLSX sheet that has 1588 observations of 15 variables. Really only interested in one column at this point, which represents one of four possible values (normal, slow, node failure, login failure). The spreadsheet is produced by an application that measures website availability. So, the goal is to simply show these four values in a pie chart. Just having some trouble with the labels and I think it's because I manually stated them and I think it needs to be based on the values instead because their numbers could obviously change in each report.

I created a variable "lbls" to hold the possible values. Their order was based on the output from the table command. I think that may be wrong and instead the labels for the pie chart really need to be based on the values in the column.

```
library(plotrix)
CN <- table(APP$urlStatus)
CN
lbls <- c("Login Failure","Node Failure","Normal","Slow")
pie3D(CN, labels = lbls,explode = 0.05,
      main="APP STG Performance")
```

Expected results are to line up the labels with the values in the column. For example, if Normal has the highest count in the column, than Normal should be displayed on that part of the pie chart. I just need to make sure the labels do in fact line up with what is being displayed on the chart. I'm not sure I have that correct because I only based their order on the output from the table command.

```
head(AppMon)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  authenticationTime pageLoadTime urlStatus Totaltime
               <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
1               3.56        11.9  Slow          15.5 
2               3.82         6.77 Normal        10.6 
3               3.86        10.6  Normal        14.4 
4               3.61        11.1  Normal        14.7 
5               5.09         4.57 Normal         9.66
6               3.03        11.8  Normal        14.8
```

[image: Pie Chart Of Values]

This is what I ended up with

```
groupStatus <- data.frame("urlStatus"=c("Normal","Slow","GSSO Login Failed",
                                        "Node Failure"))
KCW %>% group_by(urlStatus) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  right_join(groupStatus) %>%
  mutate(urlfrequency=n/sum(n,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(urlStatus,-urlfrequency),y=urlfrequency,fill=urlStatus)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  xlab("") + ylab("Frequency") + ggtitle("URL Weekly Status") +
  labs(fill="Legend") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Normal"="DarkGreen",
                               "Slow"="Yellow",
                               "GSSO Login Failed"="Red",
                               "Node Failure"="Purple"))
```

Comment: I hope that helps.

Comment: Not about the code specifically, and I know pie charts are endlessly controversial, but I think most people who regularly do data visualization would recommend [against exploding 3D pie charts](https://www.excelcampus.com/charts/pie-charts-best-practices/) for how much they distort data for no clear reason